# Is it possible to assign to two extra x-tick labels different colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I think the question says it all. I'd like to have two extra x tick labels with different colors. I thought of using a cycle command, but I couldn't figure out how it should work. I changed the color of both labels to red using

```
every extra x tick/.style={xticklabel style={color=red}},
```

and the xticklabel command is needed for a correct alignment of the labels (essentially with anchor=north).

Here comes the MWE (or MNWE):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    every extra x tick/.style={grid=none, xticklabel
      style={anchor=north, color=red}},
    extra x ticks ={0.5,1.5},
    extra x tick labels={$s_l$,$s_r$},
       ]
\addplot (x,x);  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or is this simply impossible. I'd also appreciate such an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possibility would be write a style which depends on `\ticknum`. Inside of tick label typesetting, this macro evaluates to the current tick index (starting with 0). We could (locally) define color names which contain this index - and use these indexed colors inside of the ticklabel style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    every extra x tick/.style={
        grid=none, 
        tick0/.initial=red,
        tick1/.initial=green,
        tick2/.initial=orange,
        xticklabel style={
            anchor=north, 
            color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/tick\ticknum},
        },
    },
    extra x ticks ={0.5,1.5,3},
    extra x tick labels={$s_l$,$s_r$,qr},
       ]
\addplot (x,x);  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code `<key>/.initial=<value>` instructs `\pgfkeys` to define a new (temporary) key with name `<key>` and assigns the value `<value>` to it. We can simply read that value with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/<key>}` . Macros are allowed inside of `<key>`; they will be expanded. Of course, `\declarecolor{tick0}{...}` combined with `color=tick\ticknum` would also work.

The code would complain if there are too few colors.