# How to change the color of extra grid lines according to the extra tick color

Tags: pgfplots

My problem is similar to the one described in [Is it possible to assign to two extra x-tick labels different colors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200695/is-it-possible-to-assign-to-two-extra-x-tick-labels-different-colors), so I just took the code from there. Additionaly to the different colors of the extra x ticks, I would also like to change the color of the horizontal grid lines accordingly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    every extra x tick/.style={
        grid=none, 
        tick0/.initial=red,
        tick1/.initial=green,
        tick2/.initial=orange,
        xticklabel style={
            anchor=north, 
            color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/tick\ticknum},
        },
        grid,
        grid style={densely dashed,line width=0.6pt,color=red}
    },
    extra x ticks ={0.5,1.5,3},
    extra x tick labels={$s_l$,$s_r$,qr}
       ]
\addplot (x,x);  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only builtin support to style grid colors is the distinction between x,y,z grid lines, major/minor grid lines, and the same choices for extra ticks.

There is no builtin support for individually styled grid lines.

You may need to use custom `\draw` commands to draw the special grid lines, perhaps combined with layered graphics to ensure that they are on the same layer as grid lines (see also the key `extra description` which draws stuff outside of the clipping region).

Note that tick labels are tikz nodes, and `xticklabel style` is reevaluated for every node - that makes it different from grid lines where the color is just evaluated once.