# Tikz: How to style extra tick lines separately?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My question is quite related to this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201153 - but not exactly the same thing.

Edit: I have a plot with 2 extra y ticks (see below), but I need to style the labels and lines separately.
Say, in the following example, I'd like there to be lines in the same colours as the labels and the orange line should be dashed and the blue one dotted. How can I achieve this?

```
% Simplified MWE

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots, units}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=1 by 1},
        height=8cm,
        width=8cm,
        ymax=100,
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        x tick label style={rotate=0,anchor=east}
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[
        bar width=9pt,
        symbolic x coords={ResNet18, ResNet50, Inception},
        xtick=data,
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        extra y ticks={10,50},
        extra y tick label={THIS},
        every extra y tick/.style={
        grid=major, 
        tick0/.initial=orange,
        tick1/.initial=blue,
        yticklabel style={
            color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/tick\ticknum},
            },
        },
        every node near coord/.append style={font={\tiny}}
        ]
    
        \addplot+[ybar, draw=green] plot coordinates {
            (ResNet18,32.58)
            (ResNet50,25.17)
            (Inception,26.92)};
    
        \addplot+[ybar, draw=red] plot coordinates {
            (ResNet18,60.17)
            (ResNet50,65.00)
            (Inception,66.83)};
        \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're right, my question didn't come across as intended, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with different tick styles works because of `\ticknum`. I do not think that there is a corresponding macro for the grid lines. You could just `\draw` the lines and optional also just draw the tick label at the same time like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=1 by 1},
        height=8cm, width=8cm,
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        ybar,
       ]
        \nextgroupplot[
        bar width=9pt,
        symbolic x coords={ResNet18, ResNet50, Inception},
        xtick=data,
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        every node near coord/.append style={font={\tiny}},
        clip=false, axis on top,
        ]    
        \addplot+[ybar, draw=green] plot coordinates {
            (ResNet18,32.58)
            (ResNet50,25.17)
            (Inception,26.92)};
        \addplot+[ybar, draw=red] plot coordinates {
            (ResNet18,60.17)
            (ResNet50,65.00)
            (Inception,66.83)};
        \draw[orange, dashed] ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:ResNet18,10}) node[left]{THIS} -- ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:ResNet18,10});
        \draw[blue, dotted] ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:ResNet18,50}) node[left]{THIS} -- ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:ResNet18,50});
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with orange dotted and blue dashed horizontal line]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!